# Can we create SaaS offers for Azure Gov

Tags: azure-marketplace, azure-gov

Can we publish a SaaS offering in Partner Center? 
`I dont see an option when creating an offer`. Any update on this would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. Only Virtual Machines and Solution templates are able to be published in the Azure Marketplace for Azure Government. We will have SaaS offerings and are schedule to be launched this calendar year.

To keep updated about what is possible to publish and manage in the Azure Marketplace for Azure Government please make sure to review this link frequently: [Publishing to the Azure Government Marketplace](https://aka.ms/azuregovpublish)